# As a highschool graduate what essential skills do I need before I even think about getting into UX/UI?

Tags: design, ux-field

What are important software I should master before breaking into UI/UX?

-Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to UX.SE! Please check out the [about] and [help] pages to learn more about this community. This question doesn't really have a single answer. This would be better brought to chat.

Comment: If you make it just about software tools this can be a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, this is too broad a question for us to help with in this site - we need specific questions about individual UX problems that you need a particular answer to. This is really just a 'what software is best' question and there is no correct answer to such questions, they are just polls really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different disciplines within UX that you can specialize in, however starting from a blank canvas here's what to look into:

(1) **Omnigraffle**: Excellent wireframe and diagraming software. Very popular among people in UX. Mac only.

(2) **Visio**: *Kind of* the equivalent to Omnigraffle but for PC.

(3) **Axure**: Wireframing and rapid prototyping tool. Some consider this old school but still widely used.

(4) **UX Pin**: SaaS wireframing and diagramming application. There's quite a few SaaS diagraming tools but check out UX Pin they have a 30-day free trial.

Once you know one Wireframing tool, it's safe to say that with a little practice you can master another one quite quickly.

Comment: Oh I'll look into those thanks, do I also need to learn javascript and HTML?

Comment: It really depends on what your plans are, if you want to work solely in design you can, if you want to do both design and programming you can do that too. Not necessary to learn Javascript right away but if you're working on anything web based you should probably have a basic understanding of HTML. Check out http://www.codeschool.com/

Comment: Knowing some graphic design software is useful so that you can mock up pages for clients.